# python3 manage.py findstatic can't find static file

Tags: html, css, django

I am trying to add static file to my project but css doesn't load. I used findstatic but django doesn't see any static directory:
[image]
[image]

In another project django still can find static folder:
[image]

[image]

My settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <link href = "{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel = 'stylesheet'>
    <title>{% block title %}Educa{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id = 'header'>
    <a href = "/" class = 'logo'>EDUCATION</a>
    <ul class = 'menu'>
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a href = "{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li><a href = "{% url 'login'%}">Login</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</div id ='content'>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
<script src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/
jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        {% block domready %}
        {% endblock %}
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Thank you**

Comment: What do you have the following settings set to? `STATICFILES_DIRS`, `STATICFILES_FINDERS`

Comment: Your project will probably also have static assets that aren’t tied to a particular app. In addition to using a static/ directory inside your apps, you can define a list of directories (STATICFILES_DIRS) in your settings file where Django will also look for static files. : from django documentation -- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how it even possible but i tried to rename my static folder and i found out there was an **space** after 'static'. After that css loaded BUT not for this project. It was css from another environment so i renamed it to main.css from base.css and also changed:

```
<link href = "{% static 'css/main.css' %}" rel = 'stylesheet'>
```

and everything works fine. Thank you all for help, interesting experience, sorry)